# jquery serialize and multi select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, webforms

I have been using the jquery serialize() function to serialize the values of a form and submit it via ajax

like for e.g. if the form name and id is **factoryUsers**

`var data=$("#factoryUsers").serialize();`

Now this works fine for forms that have text fields, text areas, simple drop downs etc.
But when I have a multiple dropdown , things go awry
for e.g. if I have a dropdown of the type

`<select size="5" id="factoryUsers" name="factoryUsers" multiple="multiple">`

the serialize doesn't work correctly anymore.
so if I select 3 users I get a query string like

`factoryUsers=5&factoryUsers=23&factoryUsers=11`

changing the select to array type doesn't help either `factoryUsers[]`

Any idea or help how to get this working correctly would be great.

Comment: Well, as Posted by Jordan, the Jquery is working perfectly .  I was not sure if the query string factoryUsers=5&factoryUsers=23&factoryUsers=11 would be handled correctly by the server, and it turned out it handled it perfectly as I got all the values in an array $_POST['factoryUsers'], which was an array having 3 values. Just to mention I used `factoryUsers[]`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The string output you've described above is the correct way of submitting multiple values for forms with the same name over HTTP, so jQuery is working correctly. It's up to you to handle how this is processed on the server-side, which is then dependent on what language you are using.

If you're using PHP, this may help: http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/12267-how-php-_post-gets-multiple-values-html-form

Can you tell us what language you're using?

Comment: I am using PHP. You are right , its upto the server side language to process it correctly.  I was not sure if the query string factoryUsers=5&factoryUsers=23&factoryUsers=11 would be handled correctly by the server, and it turned out it handled it perfectly as I got all the values in an array $_POST['factoryUsers'], which was an array having 3 values

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Looks like you found out about PHP's "special" way of using the [] at the end of the field name as well. Good luck with the rest of your project.

Comment: Thanks! yep I did know that PHP can process posted values for fields like factoryUsers[], but what I didn't know was values were passed like factoryUsers[]=5&factoryUsers[]=23&factoryUsers[]=11,and when I saw this query string , I thought it would not be handled perfectly, so I mistakenly posted it didn't work without testing first, thinking something is wrong. Thanks , a ton for pointing it out, which made me test again.

Answer (score 22):

Try changing the name of the select to `factoryUsers[]`. That way you can loop through it in your backend.

Answer (score 8):

All you need is change name="factoryUsers"  to name="factoryUsers[]" PHP will treat it as array.

Answer (score 6):

Your elements name must be array type **`factoryUsers[]`**
Change your code this:

```
<select size="5" id="factoryUsers" name="factoryUsers[]" multiple="multiple">
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Just try it to get value with val()

```
data='factoryUsers=' + $("#factoryUsers").val();
```

It will give you the values with comma seperate.

> factoryUsers=1,2,4

If this item is one of your form. Then try to add the value of item end of the serialize. Example:

```
data= f.serialize() + '&factoryUsers=' + $('#factoryUsers').val();
```

Since, the item written twice into the request, the last value will be valid in controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP function

```
parse_str($_POST)
```

This function seems to be an extract function. After you run this, you can access a var named `$factoryUsers`, and this var is an array `$factoryUsers[n]`.