# jquery serialize multiple select

Tags: jquery, html

How to get all form value and serialize multiple select with a given variable or an array?
output parameter must be;

```
id=1&name_1=John&name_2=Juan&name_3=Isabel&name_4=Doe
```

where the **name** is in **multiple select**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118716/jquery-serialize-and-multi-select-dropdown) demonstrates, jQuery will use the same 'name' value as the key for each selection when serializing via `$(form).serialize()`:

```
id=1&name=John&name=Juan&name=Isabel&name=Doe
```

and it's up the server to understand how to handle it.  Chances are that your server will handle it just fine.

If you absolutely require the format you mentioned, you should be able to hack it together using something like this (untested):

```
var elementArray = $(form).serializeArray();
var modifiedArray = [];
var counts = {};
var multipleValues = {};
$.each(elementArray, function(index, value) {
  if (counts[value.name]){ counts[value.name] += 1; } else { counts[value.name] = 1; }
});
$.each(elementArray, function(index, value) {
  if (multipleValues[value.name] || counts[value.name] > 1){ 
    if (!multipleValues[value.name]) { multipleValues[value.name] = 0; } else { multipleValues[value.name] += 1; }
    modifiedArray.push({name: value.name + "_" + multipleValues[value.name], value: value.value});
  } else {
    modifiedArray.push({name: value.name, value: value.value});
  }
});
var result = $.param(modifiedArray);
```

Comment: hoping that it will not crash and handled all my parameters for other mutiple select :)

Comment: how can I start the array from 0?

Comment: @mrrsb: Arrays in JavaScript are already 0-based, please explain your question a bit more.

Comment: Hi @PinnyM! above code gives me parameters like this id=1&name_1=John&name_2=Juan&name_3=Isabel&name_4=Doe... is it possible to start the multiple "name" parameter to name_0 instead of name_1?

Comment: @mrrsb: updated - compare the edit to previous version to see what needs to be changed.

Comment: @mrrsb: Your last comment was not clear - can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 5):

PHP won't handle multiple request values with same name. You can post them as an array. To do this simply add [] to the end of html element's name tag.

```
user[]=John&user[]=Bill&user[]=Adam
```

in PHP it looks like:

```
Array
(
    [user] => Array
        (
            [0] => John
            [1] => Bill
            [2] => Adam
        )
)
```

Comment: For all those who are using jquery serialize() function, with ajax method 'post', and 'select' element with 'multiple' attribute, this solves the problem.