# Serialize seems to overwrite values on multiple select and checkboxes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

The jQuery API explains how [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) can be used on a form with the following:

```
<form>
  <select name="single">
    <option>Single</option>
    <option>Single2</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  <select name="multiple" multiple="multiple">
    <option selected="selected">Multiple</option>
    <option>Multiple2</option>
    <option selected="selected">Multiple3</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check1" id="ch1">
  <label for="ch1">check1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check2" checked="checked" id="ch2">
  <label for="ch2">check2</label>

  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio1" checked="checked" id="r1">
  <label for="r1">radio1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio2" id="r2">
  <label for="r2">radio2</label>
</form>


<script>
  function showValues() {
    var str = $( "form" ).serialize();
    $( "#results" ).text( str );
  }
  $( "input[type='checkbox'], input[type='radio']" ).on( "click", showValues );
  $( "select" ).on( "change", showValues );
  showValues();
</script>
```

Which produces something like

```
single=Single&multiple=Multiple&multiple=Multiple2&multiple=Multiple3&check=check2&radio=radio1
```

it seems that `multiple` gets overridden twice. So how am I supposed to access the multiple values?

Or is there a more modern method to use than serialize?

Comment: Are you sure Multiple2 is listed?  Looking at their example, only the 'selected' values should have been serialized.

Comment: And how are you trying to "access" the values?  With JS or on the server?

Comment: @Snekse Something like `<?php if (isset($_GET["multiple"])){ $multiple = $_GET["multiple"];}`

Answer (score 1):

Add a square brackets `[]` to the select name. Then the `$_GET['multiple']` will be treated as an array.

```
<select name="multiple[]" multiple="multiple">
```

See [How do I get all the results from a select multiple HTML tag?](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.select-multiple) for more info.

Comment: I know this is the accepted PHP practice, as covered by http://stackoverflow.com/a/5118766/378151, but it seems strange and unholy to need to change your HTML just to make PHP happy.

Comment: Yep, I agree with you about having to *rename* your form inputs to accommodate to the PHP way. However, how do you know, in a generic way, that a `<select multiple>` field is an array or a single string?

Comment: @Snekse Is this the most modern way to submit a form to PHP? What's the most modern?

Comment: @thomas I have no idea.  I haven't worked with PHP in several years and even then, it was minimal.  From what I can tell though, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is doing what it's supposed to be doing.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5118766/378151

When using multiple values over HTTP GET, it will be listed multiple times with each value.

To access the values on the server will depend on the server technology you're using.  If you're using PHP, take a look at the SO answer I linked to.

A basic option though would be to grab the requested URL, evaluate the query string, tokenize on the `&`, then split again on the `=` and look at the key.  If the key is 'multiple`, then add the value to your array of values.

Comment: How do I access multiple values stored under the same variable name. When I do `<?php echo var_dump($_GET);?>` I only see the values that were set last.

Comment: Ah, the access was a server side question.  I would refer to the answer linked to.  There are a couple of options given.

Comment: What else would you do with the data if not send to and access on the server? Thanks!

Comment: Create a tag cloud? Who knows what strange things people try to do with code.  I tried to write a CFML parser in PHP once.  People do strange things.

Comment: Wouldn't all of those things require server side accomodation?