# How do I pass in an array of multiple select?

Tags: javascript, select, serialization

I use `serialize()`, but the data is not transmitted in the same array.

```
function tableoptionmain() {

var msg   = $('#list-optionform').serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    async: true,
    url: 'includes/parts/list/table/main-check.php',

    data: msg,

    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#listtable-parent').empty().html('<img style="margin: auto; display: block;" src="http://tbooklist.org/includes/front/img/loader/loaderIcon.gif" />');
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#listtable-parent').empty().html(data);
    }
});
};
```

I have something like this:

```
name1: data1
name1: data2
```

I want to get something like this:

```
name1: data1, data2
```

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**
HTML like this

```
<form method="" id="list-optionform">
<select name="name1" multiple="multiple" id="name1">
  <option value="data1">data1</option>
  <option value="data2">data2</option>
  <option value="data3">data3</option>
</select>
<a href="#" onClick="tableoptionmain(); return false;">btn</a>
</form>
```

if you select multiple options php get only the last option

Comment: it's a little unclear as to what exactly you want because what you're showing as the format you want isn't an array either.  it's also difficult to give any pointers without seeing the inputs with name = name1. you may be able to get name1[0] = value1, name1[1] = value2, etc but your form inputs would need to hold the indices (for example, one input has name="name1[0]" and another has name="name1[1]")

Comment: My English is very bad, and can not always accurately convey their thoughts :(

I'll try to more accurately describe the problem:

I pass data in php, I do not get ($ _POST ['name]) only one value: name1: data; name1: data2 - I get data2.
I do not really understand how to fix it.

Comment: When used on a val () I get the array: name1: data1, data2 ...
But I am having some difficulty + becomes quite cumbersome, so I thought that's not the best solution.

Comment: can you update your question with some of the HTML for the inputs with name = name1 ?

Comment: i update post, add example

Comment: see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118716/jquery-serialize-and-multi-select-dropdown

Comment: thank! You helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    function tableoptionmain() {

    var msg   = $('#list-optionform').serialize();
        console.log(msg);
       // split the message string by &
        var arr = msg.split("&");
        console.log(arr);

        var str = "name1 : ";
        var len = arr.length;

        for(var  i= 0;i < len ; i++){
        // split each individual arr element by =
            var temp = arr[i].split("=");
            // add data to str
            str+= temp[1]+" , ";
        }
        // remove the last ,
        str = str.slice(0,str.lastIndexOf(" , "));
        console.log(str);

   ...  rest of the code including ajax call
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer !, there was also a decision php||
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118716/jquery-serialize-and-multi-select-dropdown